# UNIQUE KEY Violation error not showing duplicated data

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssms, unique-constraint

In SQL Server 2008, while inserting a set of records to my table `table1` , i am getting a unique key violation error due to the Duplicate data. That is fine, but the error message is not showing which data is duplicated. But in SQL Server 2014 it is showing the duplicate key value also .

Error Message in 2014

> Msg 2627, Level 14, State 1, Line 2 Violation of UNIQUE KEY constraint
>   'UK_table1'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.table1'. ***The
>   duplicate key value is (xxx)***.

Error Message in 2008

> Msg 2627, Level 14, State 1, Line 2 Violation of UNIQUE KEY constraint
>   'UK_table1'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.table1'.

Is this a new feature in 2014 or is there any way to show this in SQL Server 2008?

*Note:- Hope the question is clear, if it is not please comment. Also if this is a new feature in 2008+, then please add valid reference/link for this*

**EDIT**

**2008**
[image: 2008]

**2014**
[image: 2014]

Comment: See my edited post - it seems clear from the `@@version`s of yourself and @Ponmani that it was introduced in SQL 2008 R2.

Comment: @strickt01, yes you are right, thank you. One more , is it possible to edit this sysmessages in 2008 to include this feature? Just to know?

Comment: Unfortunately not as the internal code calling `RAISERROR` won't be passing the requisite parameters to that message. You'll need to upgrade...

Comment: Thank you all, got a good lesson and a new feature.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Run the following on both servers:

```
select * from sysmessages sm where sm.error = 2627
```

You should see that the message templates are different. Which exact version of SQL Server 2008 are you using because it was definitely available in 2008 R2:

> Violation of %ls constraint '%.*ls'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object '%.*ls'. The duplicate key value is %ls.

Looking back at SQL Server 2005 databases though the template is:

> Violation of %ls constraint '%.*ls'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object '%.*ls'.

From looking at your `@@version` it is clear that it was not available in SQL Server 2008 RTM but that from @Ponmani's `@@version` that the feature was added by SQL Server 2008 R2.

Answer (score 1):

Abdul,  it seems available in SQL server 2008 itself. Please find the screenshot.

[image]

Find the  `@@version`

[image]

Comment: 10.0.1600.22 is SQL 2008 RTM. So it seems to be available from 2008 onwards. What is your version number @Abdul Rasheed?

Comment: Thanks for your reply, attached a screenshot in my question

Comment: Could you run `@@version` on yours @Ponmani Chinnaswamy? Your clients tools are definitely SQL 2008 RTM but the server may not be (or is it local?)...

Comment: @strickt01 , Please find the edited post. i have attached screenshot

Comment: It is 2008 R2, But mine is 2008, that is the diff, thanks @PonmaniChinnaswamy

Comment: yes abdul.. Please find the link  this  feature was upgraded. 

http://sqlblog.com/blogs/louis_davidson/archive/2011/07/14/denali-enhancement-duplicate-key-error-message.aspx

Comment: Useful link - although Denali was SQL 2012 - and we know from your screenshots above that the feature was already available in 2008 R2.